# Stripe cannot make make payment error in webview

Tags: flutter, stripe-payments, strip, flutter-test, flutterwebviewplugin

I'm using stripe payment gateway in my app everything works fine when i enter card details after that it redirect to the OTP page after enter otp and submit it throws this error

This problem occurs only in live mode, in test mode debit card won't ask for OTP

```
I/flutter ( 5342): errprint : PlatformException(failed, failed, null, null)
```

payment-service.dart

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:stripe_payment/stripe_payment.dart';

class StripeTransactionResponse {
  String message;
  bool success;
  StripeTransactionResponse({this.message, this.success});
}

class StripeService {
  static String apiBase = 'https://api.stripe.com/v1';
  static String paymentApiUrl = '${StripeService.apiBase}/payment_intents';
  static String secret = 'xxxMy_secretxxx';
  static Map<String, String> headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ${StripeService.secret}',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  };
  static init() {
    StripePayment.setOptions(StripeOptions(
        publishableKey: "xxxMy_keyxxx",
        androidPayMode: 'production'));
  }

  static Future<StripeTransactionResponse> payViaExistingCard(
      {String amount, String currency, CreditCard card}) async {
    try {
      var paymentMethod = await StripePayment.createPaymentMethod(
          PaymentMethodRequest(card: card));
      var paymentIntent =
          await StripeService.createPaymentIntent(amount, currency);
          print("payment intent ${paymentIntent}");
      var response = await StripePayment.confirmPaymentIntent(PaymentIntent(
          clientSecret: paymentIntent['client_secret'],
          paymentMethodId: paymentMethod.id));
          print("Payment confirm ${response.status}");
      if (response.status == 'succeeded') {
        return new StripeTransactionResponse(
            message: 'Transaction successful', success: true);
      } else {
        return new StripeTransactionResponse(
            message: 'Transaction failed', success: false);
      }
    } on PlatformException catch (err) {
      print("errprint : $err");
      return StripeService.getPlatformExceptionErrorResult(err);
    } catch (err) {
      print("errprint$err");
      return new StripeTransactionResponse(
          message: 'Transaction failed: ${err.toString()}', success: false);
    }
  }

  static Future<Map<String, dynamic>> createPaymentIntent(
      String amount, String currency) async {
    try {
      Map<String, dynamic> body = {
        'amount': amount,
        'currency': currency,
        'payment_method_types[]': 'card',
        'description': 'Software development services',
        'shipping[name]': 'Jenny Rosen',
        'shipping[address][line1]': '510 Townsend St',
        'shipping[address][postal_code]': '98140',
        'shipping[address][city]': 'San Francisco',
        'shipping[address][state]': 'TN',
        'shipping[address][country]': 'IN',
      };
      var response = await http.post(StripeService.paymentApiUrl,
          body: body, headers: StripeService.headers);
          print("check post res${jsonDecode(response.body)}");
      return jsonDecode(response.body);
    } catch (err) {
      print('err charging user: ${err.toString()}');
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

This is my pubspec.yaml

```
name: message
description: A new Flutter project.

# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  intro_slider: ^2.3.2

  firebase_auth: ^0.18.0+1
  
  cloud_firestore: ^0.14.0+2

  fluttertoast: ^7.0.2

  image_picker:  ^0.6.0+9

  shared_preferences: ^0.5.3+1

  firebase_storage: ^4.0.0

  #flutter_html: ^1.0.2

  firebase_core: ^0.5.0

  giffy_dialog:

  cached_network_image: ^2.2.0+1

  modal_progress_hud: ^0.1.3

  intl: ^0.16.1

  flutter_clipboard_manager:

  sentry: ^2.2.0
  
  timeago: ^2.0.27

  qr_flutter:

  graphql:

  image_cropper: ^1.0.2

  contacts_service: ^0.4.6

  permission_handler: ^5.0.1+1

  share: ^0.6.1

  fleva_icons: ^1.0.0
 
  google_fonts : ^0.2.0

  flutter_staggered_grid_view: ^0.3.0

  flutter_icons: ^1.0.0+1

  flutter_cache_store:

  web3dart: ^1.2.3

  bitcoins: ^1.0.3

  #bitcoinFlutter
  bitcoin_flutter: ^2.0.1

  carousel_slider: ^1.3.1

  transparent_image: ^1.0.0

  smooth_star_rating: ^1.0.3

  dots_indicator: ^1.1.0

  bip32: ^1.0.5

  bip39: ^1.0.3

  tuple:

  hex: ^0.1.2

  scoped_model: ^1.0.1

  equatable:

  crypto: ^2.1.5

  encrypt: ^4.0.2

  localstorage: 

  path_provider: 
    
  photo_view: ^0.4.0

  mime: ^0.9.6+2

  ntp: ^1.0.3

  decimal:

  virtual_keyboard:

  local_auth:

  url_launcher: ^5.7.2

  launch_review: ^2.0.0

  flutter_secure_storage: ^3.3.4

  giphy_client: ^0.2.0

  flutter_barcode_scanner:

  firebase_messaging: ^5.0.2

  font_awesome_flutter:
  
  #otpinput field
  pin_code_fields: ^5.0.1

  #otpanimation lib
  flare_flutter: ^2.0.6

  flutter_slidable: ^0.5.7

  file_picker: ^2.0.6

  ethereum_address:

  flutter_downloader:
  
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.3

  #upi payment gateway
  upi_india: ^2.1.2

  cool_alert: ^1.0.1

  #webview for paymentgateway
  #webview_flutter: ^1.0.0

  #paypal payment gateway
  http_auth: ^0.3.0

  #Razorpay payment gateway
  #razorpay_flutter: ^1.2.2

  #stripe payment gateway
  stripe_payment: ^1.0.8

  #stripeUI
  flutter_credit_card: ^0.1.3
  progress_dialog: ^1.2.2
  


dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
     - assets/img_not_available.jpeg
     - assets/flags/
     - assets/emoji/
     - assets/images/
     - assets/bg1.jpg
     - assets/giphy.png
     - assets/anime/otp.flr
     - assets/splash.png
     - assets/splashc.jpg
     - assets/json/FacebookPost.json

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that "OTP" is a "one time password" as part of a 3D Secure flow, then you can trigger this in test mode by using the [SCA regulatory test cards](https://stripe.com/docs/testing#regulatory-cards) such as the 3155 or 3184 card.

It's not clear where your error is coming from, but if you can share more detail with reproduction in test mode then someone may be able to offer more suggestions.

Comment: Thanks man for suggesting 3D Secure flow it helps me a lot in my case the issue was my debit cart did't accept international payments